# Buck Converter Output Voltage Swing problem

Tags: circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, buck, control

I am designing a voltage mode control buck converter and I have an issue with my output voltage swing. I made calculations for type 2 compansator. I can't figure the cause of problem is stability of control or simulation engine. Thanks.
EDIT: I decide compensation via given table.
[image: Compensation Table]
[image: Circuit]
[image: Vout graph]

[image: Iout graph]

Comment: You can download my free [ready-made templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) and you have a buck in VM and CM already automatically compensated by a macro. They run on the demo version Elements but for a buck VM, you need a type 3, not 2.

Comment: @VerbalKint I decide type of compensation with given table on post. Table from "Application Note AN-1162".

Comment: Your AN-1162 refers to various vendors all sharing the same number, please provide a link. It seems they claim that depending on the ESR value, and provided it is high enough, you have a zero around crossover and you could benefit from it for a decent phase margin with a type 2. This ESR is likely to move with temp so it can easily escape the area for which you believed it would help hence the type 3. Look at my [APEC 2019](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202019.pdf) seminar and you have a practical example with prototype of a buck in VM fully compensated.

Comment: [link] (https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1162.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559a8e17111a) @VerbalKint Link of Application Note.

Comment: @VerbalKint Sir i will try to add type 3 compansator on my circuit. But I don't understand the reason of my output's unwanted fast swing. In the end I select all values right. I will connect the buck's output to Horn with 12V / 2 Amps. This behavior of the circuit. Can it be ignored.

Comment: It is difficult to recommend anything beside going for a type 3 as highlighted in the 5. paragraph of your AN. I don't see any parasitics in your circuit? Check the voltage at the MOSFET source and confirm it swings between 0 V and 48 V. If not or if it is unstable, remove the op-amp and bias the (+) pin of the PWM comparator (the left-side comparator) with a simple dc source equal to 1/3rd of the ramp peak amplitude (if 1 V peak, then put 0.3 V leading to a 30% duty ratio) See if you have a clean dc output in this case and proceed by step-by-step bringing the components back in the sim.